# sunrise and sunset timezone using openweathermap api

Tags: android, android-studio

How I change the time formate in this way sunrise 6:00 and sunset 17:66    {"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0102,"country":"GB","sunrise":1489127014,"sunset":1489168699}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to change the time:

```
/**
 * @param dateObject value of time
 * @return formatted time
 */
public static String formatTime(Date dateObject) {
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
    return timeFormat.format(dateObject);
 }
```

And pass as `Date` object this: `Date dateObject = new Date(yourTimeInMilliseconds);`

Answer (score 0):

please find below sample code in pyhton for your reference. (pls include 'datetime' module)

```
from datetime import datetime
timezone = int(data['timezone'])
print('Timezone : {}'.format(timezone))

sunrise_utc = int(data['sys']['sunrise'])
sunrise_local = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(sunrise_utc + timezone).strftime('%H-%M-%S')
print('Sunrise : {}'.format(sunrise_local))

sunset_utc = int(data['sys']['sunset'])
sunset_local = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(sunset_utc + timezone).strftime('%H-%M-%S')
print('sunset : {}'.format(sunset_local))
```

Please feel free to comment your review.

Comment: I don't think this is very helpful given that the question is about Android.